# From fourier series to continuous fourier transform

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In derivation of fourier transform, we start with the fourier series coefficients. If we let $T \to \infty$, it's common to say the spacing between consecutive fourier coefficient will approach $0$, and we get a continuous spectrum rather than distinct values.

So basically by letting $\omega_0 \to 0$, $n\omega_0$ becomes $\omega$. My question is - why? Isn't it an intederminate form? Maths is not about pure manipulation of symbols, we cannot magically interpret infinitely closely spaced coefficient as a continuous variable $\omega$. No matter how infinitely close to each other these coefficient will be, there will be places "without" them. We'd like to create a function with the domain of all real numbers, right? This is what we mean by "continuous spectrum". But putting these coefficients infinitely close to each other doesn't mean it's a continuous spectrum...

[image]

[Source and derivation of fourier transform from fourier series](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419190435/http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Class/e12/Lectures/FourierXform/FourierXFormI.html)

Comment: No, you can just define a Fourier transform directly as $$\hat{f}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}f(t)\,dt$$ for any $f$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\,dx<\infty$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform for (a lot) more details on how this is done rigorously in general.

Comment: I don't see your point here. Fourier transform is a generalization of fourier series, right? I'm just asking if the transition from FS to FT is rigorous enough, i.e. how to justify the transformation from distinct values of fourier coefficients into a continuous function. It's done by noting that if we let $\omega_0 \to 0$ then we can treat $n \omega_0$ as a continuous variable. My question is - why? Because we can express any real number by $n \omega_0$ as $\omega_0 \to 0$? If so, how can we actually PROVE we really can?

Comment: You asked if that was the most rigorous definition we could come up with, so I told you "no, this is." You also asked why that change was justified, but I didn't answer that because it's basically symbol pushing and definitions of how integration works on continuous functions, and it was too tedious for me to post. Though, if you're interested, the link I posted addresses that as well in the definition section if you read it.

Comment: OK, could answer this one briefly. Can we express every real number as $n \Delta\omega$, where $n$ is an integer and $\Delta \omega \to 0$? If yes, why?

Comment: That's not a well-defined question:  if $\Delta\omega\to 0$ then it isn't fixed, so neither is $n\Delta\omega$ hence it cannot be equal to a number since numbers don't change.

Comment: Do you see what I'm getting at? We transformed a discrete function into a continuous function by calling $n\omega_0$ an $\omega$. Forget about summation, forget about integration... Why can we do this? It's more of a philosophical question.

Comment: From [these](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_24/24_1_fourier_trnsfm.pdf) lecture notes I found (although it's an informal derivation).. "In view of the discussion above, as $T \to \infty$, we can put $\omega_0$ as $\Delta \omega$ and replace the sum over the discrete frequencies $n \omega_0$ by an integral over all frequencies. We replace $n \omega_0$ by a general frequency variable $\omega$".

Comment: @AdamHughes We are not only doing substitution here. We are transforming a function of discrete variable into a function of continuous variable. What allows us to think $\omega=n\omega_0$ is continuous? You answered we cannot represent every real number in this form, because it's not a well-defined number. But in order for a variable to be continuous, is has to take every real value, right? I could have just posted this question instead of referring to fourier series, transforms etc.

Comment: Put another way, the value of $Tc_n$ is defined at integer multiples of $\omega_0$ ($n\omega_0$). You can agree on that. And by letting $\omega_0 \to 0$ we are saying that the set obtained by multiplying every integer $n$ by $\omega_0$ contains all real numbers. This is because we want $TC_n$ to be a function of continuous variable, we want it to be defined for arbitrary real number $\omega$, not just at integer multiples of some number. I'm asking if the assumption that our domain contains all real numbers is correct, and how can we prove it-It's INTUITIVE, though math is not about intuition.

Comment: What do you think, am I asking the right questions here or I'm lacking some basic knowledge?

Comment: Your concerns are reasonable. You cannot truly derive the Fourier transform from Fourier series. It is just a guiding principle to demonstrate that they are very related. It allows you in some sense to say that the Fourier transform is a continuous analog of Fourier series. I think this viewpoint is horribly mistaken because the Fourier transform has very interesting functional analytic properties which Fourier series completely lack. I prefer to think of Fourier series as a discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: A better treatment of this argument can be found in Boggess' book.

Comment: On the other hand, we can look at it differently: we can first define fourier transform, a function defined for all reals, and  then show by using steps described above that in the limit, as $T\to \infty$, fourier series converges to the fourier transform. I think this is the right way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make the transformation to the continuous transform case rigorous under restricted conditions, but it's rigorous development is more trouble than it's worth. However, the intuition in this argument is worth mentioning when trying to motivate the introduction of the Fourier transform.

The reason the argument has hung around so long is that Fourier came up his transform by using this argument. It's about the only natural and compelling derivation leading the Fourier transform; it motivated Fourier, and it's Fourier's argument. There are reasons to consider the discrete series, but Fourier's reasoning remains the only natural motivation for considering "continuous" integral versions of Fourier expansions, at least at an any reasonable elementary level.