# Can we tell if set $M$ contains all real numbers?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have a set $M=\lbrace n \Delta x : n\in\mathbb{Z} , \quad \Delta x \to 0 \rbrace$ , i.e. the set obtained by multiplying every integer by an infinitesimal. Does it contain all real numbers?

My question is related to derivation of fourier transform from fourier series. Fourier series coefficients are defined at integer multiples of $\omega_0$, thus it's a function of discrete variable. It's not defined for all real numbers, right? Allegedly it's mathematically valid to [obtain a function of continuous variable, defined for all reals, from a function of discrete variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138899/from-fourier-series-to-continuous-fourier-transform) by letting $\omega_0 \to 0$. The spacing between consecutive coefficients approaches $0$ and it becomes a function of continuous variable. It's not clear to me why it happens - probably because of what I'm asking in this question, i.e. all real numbers "are covered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real field is Archimedean; it possesses no infintesimals.

Comment: Would you be so kind and try to answer my [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138899/from-fourier-series-to-continuous-fourier-transform)?

Answer (score 0):

And even if you use a theory that allows to identify infinitesimals among the real numbers (Nelsons internal set theory), the real numbers $(n+\frac12)Δx$ are not contained in your grid.